# Inserting data into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I getting an error when attempting to insert data into my table for I don't know how to insert a primary key. The error I get is:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

My code:

```
USE BeachTennis7

INSERT INTO dbo.player (playerfname, playerlname, gender, age, [prior rank], player_id)
VALUES ('Dan', 'McClure', 'M', 21, 1, 0);
```

I understand the the `int` value cannot be converted into a key, I just don't know how to declare a primary key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a variable as a unique identifier, then add it to the insert statement.

```
DECLARE @playerId uniqueidentifier
SET @playerId = NEWID()

INSERT INTO dbo.player (playerfname,playerlname,gender,age,[prior rank],player_id)
VALUES ('Dan','McClure','M',21,1, @playerId);
```

Comment: Thank so much, makes perfect sense.

Comment: @user3325875, consider adding a default constraint on the player_id column with a value of NEWSEQUENTIALID().  This will avoid the need to specify the column and value on the insert statement and perform better than a random GUID value.

Comment: @user3325875: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

INSERT INTO dbo.player (playerfname, playerlname, gender, age, [prior rank], player_id)
VALUES ('Dan', 'McClure', 'M', 21, 1, NEWID());